# Not Able to Access Composer REST API After Restricting IP Address Through Web Server Access Control via Cloud NAT

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to trigger a composer DAG through GCF. I am able to trigger it while web server access control for network was allowing all IPs to connect but after restricting the IP the Cloud Function is throwing 403- Forbidden Error.

Below are the steps I have followed.

1. Created a VPC network, Cloud router and Cloud NAT.
2. Rerouted all the egress traffic of cloud function through serverless VPC connector.
3. Whitelisted Cloud NAT's static external IP in composer webserver access control.
4. Changed composer cfg values for Stable API.
   [image: Composer cfg]

The service account I am using for GCF has below permissions.

- Composer User
- Editor
- IAP-secured Web App User

Below is the GCF code I am using.

```
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2 import id_token
import requests


IAM_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam'
OAUTH_TOKEN_URI = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token'
# If you are using the stable API, set this value to False
# For more info about Airflow APIs see https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/access-airflow-api
USE_EXPERIMENTAL_API = False


def trigger_dag(data, context=None):

    # Fill in with your Composer info here
    # Navigate to your webserver's login page and get this from the URL
    # Or use the script found at
    # https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/main/composer/rest/get_client_id.py
    client_id = 'EXAMPLE.apps.googleusercontent.com'
    # This should be part of your webserver's URL:
    # {tenant-project-id}.appspot.com
    webserver_id = 'EXAMPLE-tp'
    # The name of the DAG you wish to trigger
    dag_name = 'cf_test'

    if USE_EXPERIMENTAL_API:
        endpoint = f'api/experimental/dags/{dag_name}/dag_runs'
        json_data = {'conf': data, 'replace_microseconds': 'false'}
    else:
        endpoint = f'api/v1/dags/{dag_name}/dagRuns'
        json_data = {'conf': data}
    webserver_url = (
        'https://'
        + webserver_id
        + '.appspot.com/'
        + endpoint
    )
    # Make a POST request to IAP which then Triggers the DAG
    make_iap_request(
        webserver_url, client_id, method='POST', json=json_data)


def make_iap_request(url, client_id, method='GET', **kwargs):

    # Set the default timeout, if missing
    if 'timeout' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['timeout'] = 90

    # Obtain an OpenID Connect (OIDC) token from metadata server or using service
    # account.
    google_open_id_connect_token = id_token.fetch_id_token(Request(), client_id)

    # Fetch the Identity-Aware Proxy-protected URL, including an
    # Authorization header containing "Bearer " followed by a
    # Google-issued OpenID Connect token for the service account.
    resp = requests.request(
        method, url,
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(
            google_open_id_connect_token)}, **kwargs)
    if resp.status_code == 403:
        print(resp.text)
        raise Exception('Service account does not have permission to '
                        'access the IAP-protected application.')
    elif resp.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(
            'Bad response from application: {!r} / {!r} / {!r}'.format(
                resp.status_code, resp.headers, resp.text))
    else:
        return resp.text
```

Can Someone please help me to sort this out?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you have set-up the IP restrictions in your project? Was The blocking of the IP address set up from Cloud NAT, or from a Cloud functions [network configuration](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings)?

Comment: I have whitelisted Cloud NAT's static external IP in composer web server access controll network and have routed all the cloud functions traffic through the Cloud NAT via cloud function's VPC connector

Comment: Since you have those services set up together, the cause of the issue might not be clear. You should narrow down the issue by rolling back the changes and reintroducing each of them separately until you start seeing the 403 error again. With that, your issue could be reproduced and easier to answer.

Comment: I have actually done that already. Everything worked pretty well until I mentioned only some specific IPs in the cloud composer web server access control list.

Comment: You can see the log and get the error message to have more information. Apparently, the problem is the configuration of the VPC with NAT. You can see this [document](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/creating#web-server-access) about configuring web server networks and how to configure shared [VPC networks](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/configuring-shared-vpc).